# What is a non-real observer?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

In wikipedia's boltzmann brains page

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_brain

It is said that: "Others argue that brains produced via quantum fluctuation, and maybe even brains produced via nucleation in the de Sitter vacuum, don't count as observers"

Why would not they count as real observers and if they are, what does that mean?

Comment: If they don't interact with the environment, or interaction with the environment causes a loss of self awareness (e.g. due to an effect like quantum decoherence). 
This speculation is the theoretical product of a zero probability event and an universe assumed to be infinite; which frankly can be used to derive any result whatsoever.

Comment: @JMLCarter thank you for your comment. There are a lot of scientists that reject/not consider boltzmann brains in their theories. For example, scientist Sean Carroll says "The issue is not that the existence of such observers is ruled out by data, but that the theories that predict them are cognitively unstable: they cannot simultaneously be true and justifiably believed." (https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.00850). Also he says that boltzmann brains misapply anthropic principle. What are the other arguments from all the other scientists to not consider boltzmann brains?

Comment: Theories that lead to Boltzmann brains as the dominant observers are pathological because a Boltzmann brain will have random experiences. So, it predicts that we should have false information in our brains.  [See also here, section 6, page 18 and further](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0208013).

Comment: @CountIblis thank you very much. I'm sorry for changing a little bit the topic but can I ask you a question about information theory and digital physics? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_physics), are you familiarized with that?

Comment: It could be argued that *we* are Boltzman brains.  We did arise through quantum fluctuations.

Comment: I find digital physics very interesting, but my ideas about that are a bit "far out" :).

Comment: @CountIblis, well, my question was focused into cellular automata/game of life models. Are you more familiarized with these?

Comment: Familiar but certainly not an expert :).

Comment: @CountIblis Could you see if you could answer it? It basically asks if a cellular automata can simulate at perfect accuracy quantum continuous processes using the continuous limit of quantum cellular automaton dynamics.  (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/414114/is-simulating-quantum-field-theoretical-equations-in-the-continuous-limit-the-sa)